# Flash Builder debugging with line numbers on exception

Tags: actionscript-3, debugging, flash-builder

Is is possible to debug actionscript via Flash Builder to see line number where exception happened? Currently i only see error code and description of error.

Any good articles are welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [compiler options](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=anttasks_4.html) panel of your run configuration, set `-debug=true`.  This should enable the output of line numbers for all stack traces, including those of uncaught errors.

Comment: In my Flash Builder there is -locale en_US, so it should be -locale en_US -debug=true or -locale en_US -debug true ?

Comment: I don't know for certain, but it should be with the `=`. I'm sure it will complain if something's not right.

Answer (score 2):

If you catch an error you can trace the result of the

```
getStackTrace()
```

method. look here: [as3 reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Error.html)